# How to read value from Word Content Control and set a value back to it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word

I am looping through all content controls in a word document and and trying to look for a value in the place holder of the content control and set a value back to it.

I typed some text in the content control area in design mode where it says "Click here to enter text" so I can look for that text and replace it with a different value when running the application. 
I see SetPlaceHolder method on ContentControl and it updates the PlaceholderText.Value with proper value and I see that when debugging the code but it will not reflect back on the word document. I dont see any Save method on ContentControl.

Also, control.PlaceholderText.Value does not give me the value I typed in the design mode.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

```
For Each oRange As WORD.Range In doc.StoryRanges     
    If oRange.ContentControls.Count > 0 Then
        For Each control As WORD.ContentControl In oRange.ContentControls
            value = CalculateValue(control.Tag)  
            control.SetPlaceholderText(Nothing, Nothing, value)
        Next
     End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out that this line

```
control.SetPlaceholderText(Nothing, Nothing, value)
```

needs to be changed to below to make it working.

```
control.Range.Text = value
```